# Can't align text with checkbox (Bootstrap v3.3.6)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm going crazy over the checkboxes in Bootstrap forms. In both Chrome and IE on my desktop computer it looks almost good (text and checkbox have almost the same alignment). In Chrome on both my tablet and smartphone the text "jumps up" a few pixels... Not a huge problem but it disturbs me and since I'm not that savvy with CSS (the reson why I use Bootstrap to begin with) I just can't figure out why. And I don't like not knowing stuff... So anyone know why the latest version of Bootstrap seem to missalign checkbox text and if there is a fix?

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="usr">Username:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9">
        <input type="text" name="usr" class="form-control" id="usr">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-sm-3" for="pwd">Password:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-9"> 
        <input type="password" name="pwd" class="form-control" id="pwd">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group"> 
    <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-9">
        <div class="checkbox">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Login</button>
            &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
            <label><input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="1">Remember me</label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The default bootstrap behavior is to vertically align the `<label>` to the `input` field. at 768px and higher, you will have 7px padding on the top, default from bootstrap.

If you are trying to align the `label` with the bottom of the input field, you will need this code:

```
@media (min-width: 768px){

.form-horizontal .control-label {
    padding-top: 14px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/aj37xu05/1/

---

If you are intending to avoid this, and have he text be flush with the top of the input field, you want to use this code:

```
    @media (min-width: 768px){
.form-horizontal .control-label {
    padding-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
}
```

### https://jsfiddle.net/aj37xu05/